# Invalid server response Magento connect on upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrading Magento from 1.8 to 1.9.
But for some reason it is not working.

I'm getting this error on initial setup:

```
/mage mage-setup .
Running initial setup...
Success
Success
Error: 
channel-add: Invalid server response for http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community
```

I also tried to install Mage_All_Latest

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
Checking dependencies of packages
Error: 
install: Package community/Mage_All_Latest failed: No releases for 'Mage_All_Latest', skipping
```

What to do? I can't do any upgrade now. List upgrades is saying that I don't have any upgrades available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appeared to be a firewall that was blocking my outgoing connections.

I turned it off with: service iptables stop

Comment: I would like to, but I have to wait two day's :)

Answer (score 0):

You will also get this response if you have not initialised

```
./mage magesetup .
```